# [AppCommons respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

AppCommons.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface AppCommons : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKRequestDelegate>
- (void) getInAppPrice : (NSString *) inAppIdentifier;
@end
```

AppCommons.m

```
#import "Config.h"
#import "AppCommons.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"


@implementation AppCommons
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;


- (void) getInAppPrice : (NSString *) inAppIdentifier {
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:inAppIdentifier ];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

    // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    for(SKProduct *product in response.products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product Price : %@",product.price);
                NSLog(@"Product Price Locale : %@",product.priceLocale);
    }
}

@end
```

*This is my class to get the cost of an in app purchase.* I am calling **getInAppPrice** method from another class using the below lines

```
AppCommons *appCommon = [[AppCommons alloc] init];
[appCommon getInAppPrice:inAppProductIdentifier];
```

*I am getting following error when response is received*

**"*** -[AppCommons respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xd4f0580**

Please help .. Thank you.

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`;  reserved for a very specific pattern (and this isn't it).

Comment: Could you share which pattern it is, so I can read up on it? Thanks. Sorry for offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are doing that within the scope of a method, like this:

```
- (void)myMethod {
    AppCommons *appCommon = [[AppCommons alloc] init];
    [appCommon getInAppPrice:inAppProductIdentifier];
}
```

which means that `appCommon` will be destroyed when the method returns.

Instead make an instance variable or property so that the lifetime of the `AppCommons` object lives past this method call.

MyClass.h:

```
@class AppCommons;
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    AppCommons *_appCommons;
}
...
@end
```

MyClass.m:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "AppCommons.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _appCommons = [[AppCommons alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)myMethod {
    [_appCommons getInAppPrice:inAppProductIdentifier];
}

@end
```

Comment: +1, I added a little more explanation, but you are definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer per se, but an explanation of the reason of the error.  The answer given by trojanfoe is absolutely correct, but doesn't exactly explain the situation.

You are calling some function that does:

```
- (void)myMethod {
    AppCommons *appCommon = [[AppCommons alloc] init];
    [appCommon getInAppPrice:inAppProductIdentifier];
}
```

Inside this function you call `getInAppPrice` which creates a new object and set's that new object's delegate as your `appCommon`.  Then that object waits in the background.

Therein lies your problem.  While that second object is waiting in the background, your `appCommon` object gets released because the code gets to the end of the function and releases `appCommon`.  If your `SKProductsRequest` delegate property were not weak then your `appCommon` would still have a retain count of 1, but since it is not then your `appCommon` has a retain count of 0 after your function ends, therefore ARC sees the memory as re-usable and frees the object.

Then you get your response in the background from your `SKProductsRequest` object.  It check's it's delegate pointer (The pointer is still a valid pointer, but it now points to a freed object (or worse, a completely different object)) to see if it responds to the delegate functions.  That is when there is a call to a freed object.

So trojanfoe's answer of make the `appCommons` object a class variable so that it is retianed past the end of your function is the proper answer.retained